# How does the abstract class access the method of the subclass?

Tags: java

```
abstract class zagazuga{

    zagazuga(){

        System.out.println("yaratıldı");

        dosomething();
    }
    abstract void dosomething();

    public void lale(){

        System.out.println("what");
    }
}
public class lagaluga extends zagazuga {

    lagaluga(){

        dosomething();
    }
    @Override
    void dosomething() {

        System.out.println("nebu");
    }

    @Override
    public void lale() {

        super.lale();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lagaluga asd = new lagaluga();

        asd.lale();

    }
}
```

I know that the object is not created from abstract classes, but when the abstract class gives a constructor, when I create the object from the subclass, the constructor of the abstract class is called first. In fact, the object of the abstract class is created, the thing that makes me think about this is super.lale () in the body of the method method I override in the subclass; I couldn't figure out whether the super is referring to the object of the upper class. I had an answer if the class was a normal class, but it was strange that this was happening in the abstract. Could someone explain how it is happening

[image: image from my computer]

Comment: There are no separate objects for super class and sub class. If you instantiate a `lagaluga` then *only one* object is created. That object is (obviously) of type `lagaluga`. During initialization of that object some code from the super class is executed, but that doesn't change the fact that the object being initialized is still of the subclass type.

Comment: I know this but why the constructor of the abstract class was called and the method (empty method) that I override in lagaluga was called in the constructor of the abstract class. Isn't it necessary to create an object before a method can be called --My language is Turkish so I may have made the wrong sentences in my questions

Comment: I know the super keyword is used to access the object of the parent class

Comment: This might just be the language barrier, but `super` does **not** access "the object of the parent class", because there **is** no other object. Just like a cast in Java doesn't create or reference a different object, `super` just tells the compiler specifically which code to invoke (in this case that you want to invoke the method of the super class), but doesn't change anything about the object.

Comment: What difference is left between a static method and a normal method if an object is not created to use the method of a class?

Comment: Of course an object must be present for a non-static method (that is the difference). But `super.` does *not* create an object. It doesn't need to, because it only works in a context where there's already an object.

Comment: I'm tiring you, sorry, I just read geeksforgeeks.org it says "The super keyword in java is a reference variable that is used to refer parent class objects." What is it called parent class object?

Comment: how can a method exist without an object ?

Comment: If the abstract class were not abstract, then would the object of that class be created if it were a normal class?

Comment: The phrase "parent class object" is misleading: There is no separate object of parent class. What `super` refers to is the *current* object (i.e. this), but treating it *as if it was just of the base class type*. You can verify it easily by printing `System.identityHashCode()` of `this` in a method and in the super classes method, you'll see that they are actually the same value.

Comment: I just learned, thank you very much. During the time I learned, I thought methods could not exist without the objects in the class they belong to. So if we wanted to use a method, we had to create its object. The l4le method in my example was used by the subclass without creating objects from the parent class.
To use a method belonging to the class in a static method, we have to create it, so if I want to use the method of the main class in a static method, I need to create that object, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a tutoring service and I don't have time for extended discussions like this.

Comment: sorry i'm just trying to learn literally not to memorize

Answer (score 2):

There is no (additional) instance of the super class.

The instance of the child class includes the members (fields and methods) of the super class - it is an extension of the super-class.

Example: `Ford` is a subclass of `Car`; every `Car` has a motor, so `Ford` also has one

Hint: there is no need to declare

```
public void lale() {
  super.lale();
}
```

if not declared (overwritten), the method from the super class will be called

---

using posted code, `new lagaluga()` will create ONE instance like:

```
lagaluga asd = +---------------------+
               | (class Object)      |  // read as members of Object
               |   <init>            |
               |   boolean equals    |
               |   int hashCode      |
               |   String toString   |
               |   ...               |
               | - - - - - - - - - - |
               | (class zagazuga)    |
               |   <init>            |
               |   void lale         |
               | - - - - - - - - - - |
               | (class lagaluga)    |
               |   <init>            |    
               |   void dosomething  |
               |   void lale         |
               +---------------------+
```

(`Object` is included in all instances, *top-parent* of any class)
(`<init>` corresponds to the constructor)
the instance has all members (fields, methods) of its class, of its parent, of its grandparent (if any), ..., of Object. The instance of `lagaluga` IS also an instance of `zagazuga` (with additional methods).

The constructor is called as part of the creation of an instance (after memory is allocated). Each constructor calls the constructor of its parent up to the constructor of `Object` (which does not have a parent). Details: [JLS 12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

<sub>the above picture would be better for fields, it is not very exact for methods - methods are not replicated in each instance, they are just part of the class definition.</sub>

Comment: I know this but why the constructor of the abstract class was called and the method (empty method) that I override in lagaluga is called in the constructor of the abstract class. Doesn't an object have to be created first before a method can be called

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes by itself have no identity. In other words, while creating a new object you have to create an object of the type `lagaluga`

So technically, the upper class already knows where the implementation is for the abstract methods (in the derived class).